# In R, how do I split each string in a vector to return everything before the Nth instance of a character?

Tags: r, sapply, strsplit

Example:

```
 df <- data.frame(Name = c("J*120_234_458_28", "Z*23_205_a834_306", "H*_39_004_204_99_04902"))
```

I would like to be able to select everything before the third underscore for each row in the dataframe. I understand how to split the string apart:

```
df$New <- sapply(strsplit((df$Name),"_"), `[`)
```

But this places a list in each row. I've thus far been unable to figure out how to use sapply to unlist() each row of df$New select the first N elements of the list to paste/collapse them back together. Because the length of each subelement can be distinct, and the number of subelements can also be distinct, I haven't been able to figure out an alternative way of getting this info.

Answer (score 2):

We specify the 'n', after splitting the `character` column by '_', extract the `n-1`  first components

```
 n <- 4
 lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Name), "_"), `[`, seq_len(n - 1))
```

If we need to `paste` it together, can use anonymous function call (`function(x)`) after looping over the `list` with `lapply/sapply`, get the first n elements with `head` and `paste` them together`

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Name), "_"), function(x) 
          paste(head(x, n - 1), collapse="_"))
#[1] "J*120_234_458" "Z*23_205_a834" "H*_39_004"
```

---

Or use regex method

```
sub("^([^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+)_.*", "\\1", df$Name)
#[1] "J*120_234_458" "Z*23_205_a834" "H*_39_004"
```

Or if the 'n' is really large, then

```
pat <- sprintf("^([^_]+){%d}[^_]+).*", n-1)
sub(pat, "\\1", df$Name)
```

Or

```
sub("^(([^_]+_){2}[^_]+)_.*", "\\1", df$Name)
#[1] "J*120_234_458" "Z*23_205_a834" "H*_39_004"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed (still have a timer preventing me from accepting the answer). For some reason I have such an issue wrapping my head around complex uses of sapply and lapply.